# Utilize a command in batch to change the Output language of the CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote a batch script and everything ran fine, however I encountered problems when I transfered the script to another computer which uses the cmd in english and I no longer could utilize the script as it looked for specific words in the german cmd output.

I currently have it set to english, and I was trying to figure out if there was a way for me to use a command which can be added at the beginning of a batch script to either check the language and change it or just ultimately change it.

On google I found something about "chcp" but that didnt seem to help either. If anyone knows of anyway to solve my problem I deeply thank you.

P.S. I am trying to change it to german if that helps.

https://github.com/Pedrov01/PingsCommandOrganiser

Feel free to ask any questions if needed!
-Kind regards

Comment: What have you tried? Which specific questions/answers on this site did you find which could assist you in determining the specific language defined for the user of your script? This site does not perform your research for you, it helps you to fix a single specific and reproducible issue with your submitted code.

Comment: A German Windows "speaks" German, an English Windows "speaks" English. Additional language support has to be installed. (especially it's not part of the standard installation) Let us know which command you want to process, maybe we can give you an "international" workaround (will be command specific, if it's possible at all - there is no "general" solution).

Comment: @Stephan what I had programmed was a range ping which then outputs the hostenames as well as their related IP addresses into a text document. The problem is that it searches for the cmd output word to guide itself. In german the words which are outputed are different than in english and I would like to see if there was an easy way to modify the cmd language without having to change the whole system language.

Comment: @Compo from what I have found online I haven't been able to find an answer to my exact problem. I have found commands to identify and alter OS languages, and command lines to output the system language. But nothing to specifically alter the CMD language with a command placed at the beginning of the batch file.

[link](https://superuser.com/questions/346498/how-do-i-change-my-cmd-exe-to-english)

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263726/change-language-in-batch-script-cmd)

Comment: IMHO you don't need to change the language, but find a method to correctly process the output no matters the language. Perhaps if you post the related output in both English and German languages and describe the desired result we could help...

Comment: I could alter my code and I can make it work, however the goal was to facilitate this and allow for my code to be able to run without me having to alter it. The code is pasted above and there you can see the outputs it looks for.

Comment: I cannot see any code in your question. Am I supposed to visit another site for it? This site expects your code to be submitted directly, and not as an image, _(helpers can copy, paste, and try it)_, so that future third party site issues do not effectively remove important parts of your qiestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to change the language if the other language is not installed. So you have to write your code language-independent. The following takes advantage that the hostname is immediately followed by the IPaddress (not sure if it's the same in *all*  languages (although I guess it is) - tested with German and English):

```
language dependent text HOSTNAME [IPADDRESS] language dependent text
```

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal 
set /p "destination=Enter destination: "
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('ping -4 -n 1 %destination% ^|find "["') do (
  for %%j in (%%i) do (
    echo %%j|find "[" >nul && (set "_ip=%%j" & goto :continue )
    set "_name=%%j"
  )
)
:continue
set _ip=%_ip:~1,-1%
set _
```